# Kubectl config within AKS

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, azure-aks

I have a cluster in Azure (AKS), in this cluster, I have 2 pools: a `System` one and a `User` one to run apps.

When executing `kubectl get pod` command inside a pod, I get the error:

```
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

the pod is running on the system node(*not working on the user node either*) in one my own namespace(let's call it `cron`)
But when running the same command in a pod belonging to the namespace `kube-system` on the system node, it's working fine.

it looks like to be link to the configuration of kubectl (kubeconfig) but I don't get how it works in the `kube-system` namespace and not the `cron` one

what did I miss in AKS to not be able to run kubectl command in pod not belonging to `kube-system` namespace?

**Edit1**:
Environment variables are different especially those linked to Kubernetes:
On the pod running under `kube-system` got the URL:

```
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT_HTTPS=443
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT=443
KUBE_DNS_PORT=udp://10.0.0.10:53
KUBE_DNS_PORT_53_TCP_ADDR=10.0.0.10
KUBERNETES_DASHBOARD_PORT_443_TCP_PORT=443
KUBERNETES_DASHBOARD_SERVICE_PORT=443
KUBE_DNS_SERVICE_HOST=10.0.0.10
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP=tcp://*****.hcp.japaneast.azmk8s.io:443
KUBE_DNS_PORT_53_TCP_PORT=53
KUBE_DNS_PORT_53_UDP=udp://10.0.0.10:53
KUBE_DNS_PORT_53_UDP_PROTO=udp
KUBE_DNS_SERVICE_PORT_DNS=53
KUBE_DNS_PORT_53_TCP_PROTO=tcp
KUBE_DNS_PORT_53_UDP_ADDR=10.0.0.10
KUBERNETES_DASHBOARD_PORT_443_TCP_ADDR=10.0.207.97
KUBE_DNS_SERVICE_PORT_DNS_TCP=53
KUBERNETES_DASHBOARD_PORT_443_TCP=tcp://10.0.207.97:443
KUBERNETES_DASHBOARD_PORT=tcp://10.0.207.97:443
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PROTO=tcp
KUBE_DNS_PORT_53_UDP_PORT=53
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_ADDR=****.hcp.japaneast.azmk8s.io
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST=*****.hcp.japaneast.azmk8s.io
KUBERNETES_PORT=tcp://*****.hcp.japaneast.azmk8s.io:443
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PORT=443
KUBE_DNS_PORT_53_TCP=tcp://10.0.0.10:53
KUBERNETES_DASHBOARD_PORT_443_TCP_PROTO=tcp
KUBE_DNS_SERVICE_PORT=53
KUBERNETES_DASHBOARD_SERVICE_HOST=10.0.207.97
```

In my own env `cron`

```
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT_HTTPS=443
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT=443
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP=tcp://10.0.0.1:443
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PROTO=tcp
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_ADDR=10.0.0.1
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST=10.0.0.1
KUBERNETES_PORT=tcp://10.0.0.1:443
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PORT=443
```

About namespaces. I labeled my own namespace with the same labels as `kube-system` but no luck.

about the config: both `kubectl config view` are coming back empty (requested inside the pod):

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters: null
contexts: null
current-context: ""
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users: null
```

Comment: Share what are the environment variables set in the pod when it's running in `kube-system` namespace and when it's running in other namespace

Comment: 1. what's the output of `kubectl config view` on bothe Pods?  2. have you added your own pod to `kube-system` namespace or just running on some standard pod ?

Comment: Thanks for comments, Edited the post.
@Nick I run my own pod from a cronjob(my own)

Comment: As to your `kubectl config view` output - what do you mean by `"both"` ? Does it also come empty on a `Pod` where you can successfully run `kubectl` commands ? I guess - not. Your `kubectl` inside the `Pod` doesn't have any data about the cluster it is supposed to connect to. _"But when running the same command in a pod belonging to the namespace kube-system on the system node, it's working fine."_ - what is the output of `kubectl config view` on that particular `Pod` ?